# How to position/resize VB6 controls for different dpi settings?

Tags: vb6

In a VB form, I am placing controls(image controls), like a banner image, a logo in an image, and a an image list for an animated circle to representing processing.

When I position these controls at 96 dpi, they are perfect. But once the dpi setting is changed to 120dpi, the controls get resized and repositioned.

How do have the same positions of the controls, over different dpi settings?

Answer (score 0):

[ActiveResize](http://www.vbgold.com/index.shtml#ActiveResizeControl) is a great tool for resizing controls automagically. It costs money, but it's definitely worth checking out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to address DPI settings at all.